# Rewriting git repo history without going through all commits

Tags: git

I'd like to collapse some ugly merges in a git repository without having to rebase all of the commits that happened since. Eg:

```
* sha0                       *
| ... ~50 commits            | ... ~50 commits
*                            *
* sha1             -->       * sha1
|\                           * sha2
* *                          *
* |\                         ...
|/  *
*   |
*  /
| /
|/
* sha2
*
...
```

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Edit:

After trying a suggestion in one of the replies I realized that I should clarify:

- I'd like to rewrite the history between sha1 and sha2
- I need to retain the commits that are between sha0 and sha1

Comment: Just to clarify, in which direction does time flow? Are the children at the top or at the bottom of your ASCII graph?

Comment: Newest-to-oldest top-to-bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually you will end up rebasing. A simple way could be creating temporary branch at `sha1`, followed by a `soft reset`, and then rebase.

```
git checkout -b temp_branch sha1

git reset --soft sha2

git commit -m <message>

git checkout master

git rebase --onto temp_branch sha1

git branch -d temp_branch
```

Comment: Does the `reset --onto sha2` include the commits between 1 and 2 or is it just moving the one to the other?

Comment: git reset --soft sha2 will move the head to sha2 keeping all your changes in the staging area which you can commit.

Comment: I just tried this and you still need to go through the rebase across the first 50 commits.